# BASH: replacing quotes and checking if empty

Tags: linux, bash

I can replace a single quote by two quotes.
But I also need to check if a value is empty.

Following code returns: 
it's: command not found

```
original="it's smth"
modified=${original:-NULL}
$modified=${modified//\'/\'\'}
echo "$modified"
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `$modified=${modified//\'/\'\'}` -- you don't use `$` on the left-hand side of the =

Comment: Voting to close as a typo; it's really not clear why the OP would think that `$` is necessary in the last assignment but not the first two.

Answer (score 0):

In the third line, remove the leading `$`.

Answer (score 0):

The way bash is reading your commands:

`original="it's smth"` bash received a variable called `original` and all is well

`modified=${original:-NULL}` bash receives a second variable called `modified` that defaults to the first.

`$modified=${modified//\'/\'\'}` bash is told to process/run something because the line begins with `$modified` because of the `$`. Taking the previous string as now commands, it gets stuck right away because the first piece of that command `it's` is indeed not found among its known commands.

`echo "$modified"` is returned without an error only because here - after `echo` - the `$` is a reference to your second line, telling bash to reproduce that variable called 'modified' that was equal to 'original'. The output is `it's smth`